# Как перевести фразы темы для мультиязычности в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin, wordpress-multisite

Для мультиязычности сайта использую плагин Bogo.

Он переводит прекрасно тексты страниц, но не могу разобраться, как переводить тексты в HTML-коде.

Вроде для этого существует ф-ция

```
__( 'Режим работы:', 'pure' );
```

Но как ее адаптировать для мультиязычности сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо подготовить шаблон(плагин) для перевода

Нужно выполнить следующие действия

1. Сообщить wordpress где искать Ваш перевод

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'theme_load_textdomain');

function theme_load_textdomain() {

              load_plugin_textdomain('pure', false, dirname( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '/languages/' );

}
```

2. Создать файлы переводов

   - .pot (Portable Object Template) – шаблон, который содержит ссылку на каждую строку текста в вашей теме, которая нуждается в переводе. Файл не содержит перевода. Это обычный текстовый файл.
   - .po (Portable Object) – созданный из .pot файла, .po содержит все строки и их переводы на один конкретный язык. Это тоже текстовый файл, который можно редактировать.
   - .mo (Machine Object) – бинарная версия .po файла. При использовании машинного кода, файл может использоваться гораздо быстрее, чем текстовый его вариант.
3. Все тексты должны быть оформлены через специальные функции перевода.

Основные функции:

- __() – (два нижних подчеркивания) базовая функция, которую вы будете использовать в большинстве случаев. Возвращает текст на правильном
  языке.
- _e() – то же самое ,что __() , но она выводит текст вместо того, чтобы возвращать его.

Документация от wordpress https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/